# How to get header values in .csv file generated in non gui mode of jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am using Apache Jmeter version 4.0.
I have created one Jmeter script in Gui mode .Using below steps have executed the jmter script.It gentrates reports in .csv file.

Steps to execute the Script

1.Open command promt
2.move to jmter bin folder.
3.Execute the below command

```
C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin>jmeter -n -t C:\apache-jmeter- 4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin\examples\Post_call_24_FirstStep_10.jmx -l C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin\examples\CSVDATATest.csv
```

jmeter.property file values

```
#jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true
```

It generates repots in .csv file

[image: Header is missing in .csv file]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JMeter will only print the headers in .jtl results file if the file:

1. Does not exist
2. Or it is empty

If you have a single line there - JMeter will not add any header, it will just append new results to the existing file.

So I would suggest taking the following steps:

1. Add `-f` command-line argument to your command, this way JMeter will delete the previous results and create a brand new file having results of the current run with (hopefully) headers generated. The full command-line just in case:

   ```
   C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin>jmeter -f -n -t C:\apache-jmeter- 4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin\examples\Post_call_24_FirstStep_10.jmx -l C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin\examples\CSVDATATest.csv
   ```
2. If there still will not be headers add one more command line argument so you will be totally sure that the property is set: `-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true`. Full command line just in case:

   ```
   C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin>jmeter -f -n -t -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true C:\apache-jmeter- 4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin\examples\Post_call_24_FirstStep_10.jmx -l C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin\examples\CSVDATATest.csv
   ```

More information:

- [Full list of command-line options](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)
- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Results File Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)

Comment: Getting header with above script . with -f  command line argument